# How to create webpage preloading bar by jquery?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create a jQuery loading bar? (like the ones used on flash sites)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442363/how-to-create-a-jquery-loading-bar-like-the-ones-used-on-flash-sites)

I want to make an animated preloading bar on page before the whole webpage being loaded, it should wait until the whole webpage is fully loaded , including images,media,scripts,css,ajax,div etc, how do I know are those elements actually loaded ?

And what is the best way to create a loading bar like that? use a div to cover all the elements before they are loaded? But I see the div will blink.