# Building a Progress bar for Loading everything before display

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, progress-bar, loading

Hello i really try and search before ask.. Im trying to use jquery for a progress bar, i found a lot of info, the problem is most of the examples are just "animations" i mean, they dont really display the %, of the loading process.. and i cant find a way to do it.

Im trying to use this http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/791/Very-Beautiful-CSS3-And-JQuery-progress-bar

Mixed With the correct answer on this question. [how to create a jQuery loading bar? (like the ones used on flash sites)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442363/how-to-create-a-jquery-loading-bar-like-the-ones-used-on-flash-sites)

But i just can´t manage to merge

```
$.when($.ajax("video1.ogv"))
.then(function () {
    videoLoaded[1] = true;
    updateProgressBar();
});

$.when($.ajax("video2.ogv"))
.then(function () {
    videoLoaded[2] = true;
    updateProgressBar();
});

$.when($.ajax("video3.ogv"))
.then(function () {
    videoLoaded[3] = true;
    updateProgressBar();
});

var updateProgressBar = function() {
    // iterate though the videoLoaded array and find the percentage of completed tasks
    $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", percentage);
}
```

So the bar on CSS that i show you .. really display the % that has been loading of the content of #main_content or a video like in example..

Hope i make my self clear because my english its very bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do something like this? Just change it for AJAX and use `success` as your trigger. Basically a never ending animated gif while waiting for you data loading.

```
<div id="chartDiv"></div>

var chartDiv = document.getElementById("chartDiv");
var loadingImg = document.createElement("img");
var newImg = document.createElement("img");

loadingImg.src = "http://i1267.photobucket.com/albums/jj559/rizkytanjo96/loading.gif";
chartDiv.appendChild(loadingImg);

function placeLoaded() {
    chartDiv.removeChild(loadingImg);
    chartDiv.appendChild(newImg);
}

function getNew() {
    newImg.addEventListener("load", placeLoaded, false);
    newImg.src = "http://i1276.photobucket.com/albums/y462/staffpicks/Animated_GIFs/ahhhh.gif";
}

setTimeout(getNew, 10000);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/GYE3d/)

Alternatively, if you don't want an animated gif, you could do something like this with javascript.

```
#pwidget {
    background-color:lightgray;
    width:254px;
    padding:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid gray;
}
#progressbar {
    width:250px;
    padding:1px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:28px;
}
#indicator {
    width:0px;
    background-image:url("http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/269/shadedgreen.png");
    height:28px;
    margin:0;
}
#loading {
    text-align:center;
    width:250px;
}

var pwidget = {
    maxprogress: 250,
    actualprogress: 0,
    itv: 0,
    delay: 10,
    prog: function () {
        if (pwidget.actualprogress >= pwidget.maxprogress) {
            clearInterval(pwidget.itv);
            return;
        }

        var indicator = document.getElementById("indicator");

        pwidget.actualprogress += 1;
        indicator.style.width = pwidget.actualprogress + "px";

        if (pwidget.actualprogress === pwidget.maxprogress) {
            pwidget.restart();
        }
    },
    start: function () {
        pwidget.itv = setInterval(pwidget.prog, pwidget.delay);
    },
    stop: function () {
        clearInterval(pwidget.itv);
    },
    restart: function () {
        pwidget.actualprogress = 0;
        pwidget.stop();
        pwidget.start();
    },
    element: function () {
        var pwidget = document.createElement("div"),
            progressbar = document.createElement("div"),
            indicator = document.createElement("div"),
            loading = document.createElement("div");

        pwidget.id = "pwidget";
        progressbar.id = "progressbar";
        indicator.id = "indicator";
        loading.id = "loading";
        loading.textContent = "Loading ...";

        progressbar.appendChild(indicator);
        pwidget.appendChild(progressbar);
        pwidget.appendChild(loading);

        return pwidget;
    }
};

var chartDiv = document.getElementById("chartDiv");
var widget = pwidget.element();
var newImg = document.createElement("img");

function placeLoaded() {
    pwidget.stop();
    chartDiv.removeChild(widget);
    chartDiv.appendChild(newImg);
}

function getNew() {
    newImg.addEventListener("load", placeLoaded, false);
    newImg.src = "http://i1276.photobucket.com/albums/y462/staffpicks/Animated_GIFs/ahhhh.gif";
}

chartDiv.appendChild(widget);
pwidget.start();
setTimeout(getNew, 10000);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/bXxcg/)

Or [jQueryUI has a progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) and you could do a similar thing to my example above.

Comment: Thanks! very usefull , this is perfect, how many frames are my best option for a low gif loading... i may build a custom one so if you have anyidea it would be great to know. By the way the faces after loading are the best part jajaja :D nice.

Comment: Man but again there is a timer on the code, so if i put one second it will wait one second before display, even if there are still loading elements on the web-..... :( the point is everything is loaded before i display the page!!.. if not, what is the point of a loading ....  I need something that checks if something is loading, and just when its loaded it can display the page.

Comment: That is exactly what "load" events do, they fire only when something has completed loading. So, I'm not sure what you are struggling with. The timer/delay in my second example is only there to increment the green bar to give a feeling of something happening, set it as low as 1 milisecond (currently 10 milliseconds) or what you want. And change the number of steps if you want it to fill even quicker.

Comment: thanks to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435015/how-can-i-make-the-browser-wait-to-display-the-page-until-its-fully-loaded i give you the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason most sites have moved to a loading gif over a percent is because the percent is really unreliable.

You could possibly be in a situation where you are showing the actual progress as an exact percent then something happens causing traffic to slow down and frustrates the user when it take 5s to load 75% and then 10s to load 25%.  Tere are plenty of examples but I will stop here.

If it is at all possible I would take a loading approach over a percent don't approach for this reason alone. As long as there is an indication of work being done users are generally happy.

[EDIT] sorry it took me a little bit to get back to this and give you an example.
this is really basic and really depends on how you are showing this loading bar as to how you will add it to the page. Focus is on this line

```
$('<div>').progressbar({ value: false })
```

hope this helps. The [jQuery progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) does allow for percentage, still i would try to avoid it unless its absolutely required.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        function show_loading()
        {
            $('<div>').dialog
                ({
                    title: 'loading...',
                    modal: true,
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false
                })
            .append($('<div>').progressbar({ value: false }));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="show_loading" onclick="show_loading();">show loader</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but what if the loading bar ends before, and the page is still loading, this is what i want to avoid... I really want everything loaded before the page is displayed to my user.  whats my best option for that...... And can you show me an example with a GIF with the characteristics y just mention. thanks!

Comment: That's why the never ending ones have become so popular. Circle loaders or candy stripe bars [preloaders](http://preloaders.net/)

Comment: CAn you pls point me to an example or an article, or something pls, i will search "never ending loading bar", thanks.