# Adding a progress bar - dc.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, dc.js

I wanted to add a progress bar for the dc.js charts.

I'm doing some visualization on some huge data. And when I open the browser open the html elements loads first without any graph on the web page.

It looks horrible only when the html elements are visible.

And after a while the charts show up.

Any suggestions like how to add a progress bar will help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408661/show-progress-loader-while-asynchronously-loading-and-processing-csv-files) may help.

Comment: How can we get the start and end point of it through jquery ajax?